# "Working folder's changing" feature for StarTeam folder's object

Tags: starteam

I need to reproduce partly a behavior of StarTeam 2005 client's dialog box **"Folder Properties"** in my tool based on StarTeam 2005 SDK. Unfortunately, when I has tried to implement *"working folder's changing"* feature I has confronted with some trouble.

I has found read/write **IStFolder** object's properties **DefaultPathFragment** and **AlternatePathFragment**, but cann't to find any method/property what allows to switch between deafult/alternate paths' usage.

Also, named properties' changes always stores locally only, never stores on server, even after **update()** method usage (as opposite to, e.g., **Name** property's changes)

Can I to implement named functionality somehow?

Comment: Where did you find the working folder's changing feature in the GUI?  I can't find it anywhere in my copy of Starteam 2005.

Answer (score 0):

While working with the SDK, the "*Alternate Path to Folder*" is not kept in any way,
and once the session is closed (i.e.: your tool stops running) - that information is forgotten -
in other words: **the *Alternate Path to Folder* is not persistent**.

Note also that whatever "*Alternate Path to Folder*" you have set in your **StarTeam Client**,
this information **will not be available** to the **StarTeam SDK** session,
even if you run it on the same PC as the same user.